# New Permissions Added Warning

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-sms

I am updating the apk of my app in the playstore. The recent change that I have done is that I am using SEND_SMS feature now. I have mentioned the same in the AndroidManifest.xml and also requesting the permission in the code.

following is the snapshot of AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.user.xxx">

<!-- set this permission to be able to write/read to the sd card and internet-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Following is the snapshot of onStart method where I'm requesting all the permissions

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 10);
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 10);
        }
    }
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET))
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 11);
        else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 11);
    }
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 12);
        else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 12);
    }
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS))
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 13);
        else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 13);
    }
}
```

After I've added the SEND_SMS feature (it is crucial for the app and thus required), I'm not able to rollout a new release in the playstore as I'm facing the following warning incessantly
[Playstore warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HShRp.png)

I have done following to get rid of the warnings
1. Retain the previous apk as suggested in the "Device Support removed" warning
2. As was suggested by the community here I have added a privacy policy page and mentioned that in the store listing of the app. Following is the privacy policy page 
[Privacy_Policy](http://lictoday.com/privacy_policy/)
3. I have also added about this new permission in the "What's new in this release" text as suggested in the warning page.

After retaining the old apk, I'm able to get rid of the second warning but the first warning is not going.

Please help me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't get any problems, it's only a warning. Of course you are aware that people will get that dialog when try to update the app.

There is not a problem to solve here, it's only a warning, you can live with it happily. Just ignore it, because it is warning you of a thing you already know and accept. Just let it go

Comment: I read online that one should refrain from rolling the apps while with a warning. Thats my concern. I hope I will not face any long term problem from google with my playstore account.

Comment: @Pamo no, it's not a problem. It's only the web warning you of some dialogs your updating users will see. Nothing wrong (of course) on what you are currently doing, don't worry :)